# Filter column interval year to month

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i have column it`s look like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Nwh.png it is format +Year-Month an i need to extract some information for example:

- If the period is 0 return "No Warranty"
- if the period is more than 0  return number year number months ...

any suggestion how to approach, I know I have to use some Case  or IF Else structure

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using as you have tagged both Oracle and SQL Server and they have different syntax.

Comment: and how do you want your result exactly? Like 1 column containing the text: "`1 year(s) and 3 month(s)"`?

Comment: i`m using Oracle

Comment: it`s task i dont know to to approach. If in the row the value is +00-00 in stead it has to visualize "No Warranty" . If the value is for example+01-06 it has to visualize 1 year and 6 months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT warranty_period,
       CASE warranty_period
       WHEN INTERVAL '0-0' YEAR TO MONTH
       THEN 'No warranty'
       ELSE TO_CHAR(warranty_period)
       END AS descr
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (warranty_period) AS
SELECT INTERVAL '0-0' YEAR TO MONTH FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '0-1' YEAR TO MONTH FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '1-0' YEAR TO MONTH FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '1-2' YEAR TO MONTH FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| WARRANTY_PERIOD | DESCR |
| --- | --- |
| +00-00 | No warranty |
| +00-01 | +00-01 |
| +01-00 | +01-00 |
| +01-02 | +01-02 |

Or, if you want a different format then `EXTRACT` the component parts:

```
SELECT warranty_period,
       CASE warranty_period
       WHEN INTERVAL '0-0' YEAR TO MONTH
       THEN 'No warranty'
       ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM warranty_period) || 'y ' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM warranty_period) || 'm'
       END AS descr
FROM   table_name
```

Which outputs:

| WARRANTY_PERIOD | DESCR |
| --- | --- |
| +00-00 | No warranty |
| +00-01 | 0y 1m |
| +01-00 | 1y 0m |
| +01-02 | 1y 2m |

or:

```
SELECT warranty_period,
       CASE 
       WHEN warranty_period <= INTERVAL '0-0' YEAR TO MONTH
       THEN 'No warranty'
       WHEN warranty_period < INTERVAL '1-0' YEAR TO MONTH
       THEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM warranty_period) || ' months'
       WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM warranty_period) = 0
       THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM warranty_period) || ' years'
       ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM warranty_period) || ' years and ' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM warranty_period) || ' months'
       END AS descr
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

| WARRANTY_PERIOD | DESCR |
| --- | --- |
| +00-00 | No warranty |
| +00-01 | 1 months |
| +01-00 | 1 years |
| +01-02 | 1 years and 2 months |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qt-KyuCi)